# socketio cookies are always empty; header "Set-cookie" is not being set

Tags: javascript, curl, cookies, socket.io, webserver

Im building a webserver with express, socketio and react. I have barely any experience when it comes to server and client communication, so Im trying to figure everything out.

**Goal**
Everytime a client connects to the webserver, it should be tested wether a cookie with the name "uid" exists. If it does, I want to print the value to the console, if there is no cookie with the name "uid" I want to create one.

**Problem**
Whenever I access `http://localhost:3000` (on which adress the react client is hosted) and inspect the localhost request, there is no header with the name `Set-header`, same happens when I try to `curl` it. Also, in the Application tab the Cookies for `http://localhost:3000` are completely empty. Accessing the cookie that should be set when a socket connects results in `undefined` or an empty object.

**What I tried**

- [The docs](https://socket.io/how-to/deal-with-cookies#cookie-based-sticky-session) suggest setting `cookie: true` inside the options when creating the server, and prove that the cookie is set with a `curl`. I also tried setting the options to `true` on server creation (see server source code below), however when I try to `curl` the line `Set-Cookie: io=G4J3Ci0cNDWd_Fz-AAAC; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax` doesnt show up (see curl output below).
- Following [the docs](https://socket.io/how-to/deal-with-cookies#application-cookies) again, I tried setting a cookie via `headers["set-cookie"] = cookie.serialize("uid", "1234", { sameSite: "strict" });` inside `io.engine.on("initial_headers")`, however the cookie property on `socket.request.headers.cookie` remains `undefined` when trying to parse the cookie via `let cookies = socket.request.headers.cookie; let parsed = cookie.parse(cookies ?? ""); //does not translate console.log(parsed);` and thus the console output is only an empty `{}`.

I dont know what the difference between `cookie based sticky session` and `application-cookies` is, and I also dont know much about settings cookies and headers and all that stuff, maybe I am missing something obvious about the server/client side. Thanks in advance

`Curl` output:

```
C:\Users\stadl>curl "http://localhost:3000" -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1711
< ETag: W/"6af-+M4OSPFNZpwKBdFEydrj+1+V5xo"
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 13:29:44 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const ports = require("../ports");
const cookie = require("cookie");

const SERVER_PORT = ports.get("server");
const CLIENT_PORT = ports.get("client");

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:" + CLIENT_PORT,
    },

    cookie: true,
});

io.engine.on("initial_headers", (headers, request) => {
    headers["set-cookie"] = cookie.serialize("uid", "1234", { sameSite: "strict" });
});

io.engine.on("headers", (headers, request) => {
    if (!request.headers.cookie) {
        return;
    }

    const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookies);

    if (!cookies.uid) {
        headers["set-cookie"] = cookie.serialize("uid", "abc", { maxAge: 86400 });
    }
});

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log(`socket ${socket.id} connected`);

    let cookies = socket.request.headers.cookie;
    let parsed = cookie.parse(cookies ?? "");
    console.log(parsed);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log(`socket ${socket.id} disconnected`);
    });
});

server.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on http://localhost:" + SERVER_PORT);
});
```

Client code:

```
import React from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

import Navigation from "./components";

import { reload } from "./reload";

const ports = require("ports");
const SERVER_PORT = ports.get("server");

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            DARKMODE: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(reload, 1000);
    }

    toggleDarkMode() {
        this.setState({
            DARKMODE: !this.state.DARKMODE,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app" data-theme={this.state.DARKMODE ? "dark" : "light"}>
                <Navigation onDarkModeToggle={this.toggleDarkMode.bind(this)}></Navigation>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

#### ----------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------

When activating the `show filtered out request cookies` in chrome on inspecting the localhost request, the cookie "uid" with the value "abc" gets displayed. But why is it getting filtered out?